# Error when importing realm config for keycloak within a docker container

Tags: docker, import, keycloak

I deployed the keycloak on the docker by the below command:

```
docker run -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin -p 8080:8080 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.1 start-dev
```

And I connected to the container using:

```
docker exec -ti <CONTAINER> bash
```

And I created a realm config file as /tmp/realm.json

And finally, I ran the command:

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh import --file /tmp/realm.json
```

But I encountered with the errors as below:

```
2022-09-26 21:40:37,142 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (main) KC-SERVICES0010: Failed to add user 'admin' to realm 'master': user with username exists
2022-09-26 21:40:37,447 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (import_export) mode
2022-09-26 21:40:37,448 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Unable to start HTTP server
2022-09-26 21:40:37,448 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusBindException
2022-09-26 21:40:37,449 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

Hope to hear any suggestions and solutions to the problem, thank you in advance!

Comment: can you share the realm.json file?

Comment: I'm figuring the same problem while exporting. Adding some environment variables seems to help (still I get some problems, though!):
docker run `
 -it `
    --rm `
 -v ${PWD}/keycloak-data:/export `
 -e KC_DB_URL_HOST=<dbhost> `
 -e KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432 `
 -e KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=<dbname>`
 -e KC_DB_USERNAME=<dbusername>' `
 -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=<dbpassword> `
 --network <network> `
 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.2 `
 export --realm <realmName> --dir /export